# How to drag the layout only vertical in app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation, android-view

[image]

Hi everyone. I want to make a view like above. On the same screen , I have got two different layout (or it can be fragments, doesn't matter for now.). User can swipe both layout on long touch and drag/drop like above. Do you know how can we do it or is there any library for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please check [DragLinearLayout](https://github.com/Cthu/DragLinearLayout) libray.
Hope for help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Drag sort library](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview%22Drag%20sort%20library%22)

but i think this assumes that you use a listview.

Comment: thanks for comment but I can't use listview, each layout will be custom and different, so the listview is not the useful.